# Correct way for deploying dbt with docker and cloud run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run, dbt

I'm trying to deploy dbt on a Google cloud run service with a docker container. following [david vasquez](https://github.com/davidgasquez/dbt-docker) and [`dbt` Docker images](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/tree/dev/octavius-catto/docker)  However when trying to deploy the builded image to cloud run. I'm getting an error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update &&                 apt-get dist-upgrade -y &&                 apt-get install -y  --no-install-recommends                     git software-properties-common make build-essential                     ca-certificates libpq-dev &&                 apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY requirements/requirements.0.17.0rc4.txt ./requirements.0.17.0rc4.txt 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install dbt==0.17.0 
RUN pip install --requirement ./requirements.0.17.0rc4.txt


RUN useradd -mU dbt_user

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PORT = 8080
ENV HOST = 0.0.0.0

WORKDIR /usr/app
VOLUME /usr/app

USER dbt_user
CMD ['dbt', 'run']
```

I understand the health check fails because it can't find a port to listen to, except i specify one in my `ENV`

Can anyone help me with a solution? thx in advance

Comment: I think (I'm not familiar with it) that `dbt` is a command-line app. It appears that way looking at David Vasquez's repo. Cloud Run is only for apps that expose an HTTP interface and then one that can be configured to run on port `${PORT}`. So I think you may be out of luck trying to use Cloud Run

Comment: Using `dbt run` doesn't start an application to listen on `${PORT}`, so as @DazWilkin mentioned, you won't be able to use Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port) one of the requirements to deploy an application on Cloud Run is to listen requests on `0.0.0.0` and expose a port:

> The container must listen for requests on 0.0.0.0 on the port to which requests are sent. By default, requests are sent to 8080, but you can configure Cloud Run to send requests to the port of your choice.

`dbt` is a [command line tool](https://blog.getdbt.com/what--exactly--is-dbt-/) which means it doesn't expose any PORT, hence when you're trying to deploy Cloud Run and it verifies if the build is listening it fails with the mentioned error.